# Get the sum of partial value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider there is a table `tableA`

```
col1 col2

1    some random string and number 1213 aa5 string aaasome number
2    some random string 432682 aa3 test
1    aa7
```

I need to get the result as below.

```
1   12
2    3
```

group by col1 and the result will be 5+7 (the partial int after the 'aa' string)

To add more clarity to the question,the col2 has some other strings as well.. like test test test aa2 again test test 23u45 ajsdk 4834... . Here i need to pick the 2 alone.

kindly suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Why the data is stored like that in first place?

Comment: Is it always two characters ?

Comment: @Prdp Its a old data, we now need that. it will be always a same string (not aa, i just mentioned like that) followed by a integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the prefix, cast to a number, and sum.  One method looks like:

```
select col1, sum(cast(replace(col2, 'aa', '') as number)
from tablea a
group by col1;
```

Comment: @user3763227 . . . That is exceedingly vague and not helpful.

Comment: I'm getting this error.. sorry for not mentioning..Error: 01722
DBD::Oracle::st fetchall_arrayref failed: ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtFetch) [for Statement

Comment: @user3763227 . . . You have values in the column that are other than "aa<digits>".

Comment: Yes, i have other values as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to get the required digits from the string:

```
Select col1, sum(regexp_replace(col2,'(^|.*\s)aa(\d+)(\s.*|$)', '\2'))
From t
Group by col1
```

#### [demo](http://rextester.com/KXVWF99325)

Comment: To add more clarity to the question,the col2 has some other strings as well.. like `test test test aa2 again test test 23u45  ajsdk 4834..`. . Here i need to pick the 2 alone.

Comment: @user3763227 - but your question don't explains that case, this is not good. you should ask another question then, with better explanation.

Comment: @user3763227 Updated the answer. Please try now

Comment: getting an error as `Error: 01722
DBD::Oracle::st fetchall_arrayref failed: ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtFetch) [for Statement`